# Can I store my sklearn Isolation Forest estimator values and build a new model later with those values?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, training-data, anomaly-detection

I am able to build an Isolation Forest for anomaly detection. However, due to storage limitations, I cannot store all the data I used to train it. I would also like to input more data later.

I was wondering if it's possible for me to get the estimator values when I originally train it, and save those. Then, a week later when I want to retrain the model with some newly acquired data, could I first restore my old model using those stored estimator values (so I don't need to be able to access the old data), and then the model would adapt to the newly added values.

The reason I have chosen to resort to this is because I couldn't find any algorithms for anomaly detection that learn iteratively (so a free, open source suggestion in that department would work great too!)

Any help with this would be deeply appreciated!

Comment: You can save and load the model parameters (`get_params` and `set_params`), but it doesn't look like sklearn's IsolationForest supports iterative learning..

Comment: @Blorgbeard Using the `get_params` and `set_params` will only change the hyper-parameters of the model, not the learned parameters (coefficients). You are correct that it doesn't support iterative learning. In scikit, only models having a [`partial_fit()` method have online learning](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html#incremental-learning).

Comment: @VivekKumar oh, I didn't realize that. Thanks.